# What does `~0>>-3` mean?

Tags: c

```
#define BITMAP_LAST_WORD_MASK(nbits) (~0UL >> (-(nbits) & (BITS_PER_LONG - 1)))
```

This is the operation of bitmap in Linux. `nbits` is 3 and `BITS_PER_LONG` is 64. I thought the expression should be `~0UL >> -3` and the result means I have three items. In the expression I do the `&` first and add `-`. Maybe the expression has been wrong already.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The negative shift count is a real problem here.   "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact expression? Can you please tell where exactly you saw this?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, noticed it after commented.

Comment: The behavior of `~0>>-3` is not defined by the C standard, and I doubt it is defined by GCC or other tools used on Linux.

Comment: May I ask *why* you "thought the answer should be 0x7"?

Comment: Do you know the type of `nbit` and `BITS_PER_LONG`?

Comment: Did you take care of operator precedence? Unary `-` has higher precedence than `&`. That means whatever `nbits` holds, you chop the higher bits and limit to `63`. That also kills the sign bit and yields a positive value. As a result your expression is `(~0UL >> 61)`

Comment: For those who wanted a reference, here is a patch that introduces this line: https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-sh/patch/20210321215457.588554-4-yury.norov@gmail.com/

Comment: `#define BITS_PER_LONG 64` ,so it maybe `int`.`#define NR_CPUS  CONFIG_NR_CPUS`,and CONFIG_NR_CPUS is defined in Kconfig and I set it as 3,so it may also be `int`.

Comment: I made mistakes in operation precedence.

Comment: Yanel, Why does the title use `~0`, yet code uses `~0UL`?

Comment: @Yanel Please, in the future do not make uninformed assumptions and simplifications of something you don't fully understand when posting a question. This is to avoid the confusion that you could see here. Your initial "simplified" version of the question is completely different from what you actually wanted to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `nbits` is nonnegative, `-(nbits) & (BITS_PER_LONG - 1)` computes `BITS_PER_LONG - nbits%BITS_PER_LONG` except that, if `nbits` is a multiple of `BITS_PER_LONG`, it produces zero instead of `BITS_PER_LONG`.

`~` inverts all the bits in its operand, so `~0UL` is a `long` with all its bits set. Shifting this right by `BITS_PER_LONG - nbits%BITS_PER_LONG` shifts zeros into the high bits, leaving only the low `nbits` set to one. Since the expression shifts by the `&` expression rather than `BITS_PER_LONG - nbits%BITS_PER_LONG`, if `nbits` is zero, it does not shift at all, leaving all bits set.

Thus the result of `(~0UL >> (-(nbits) & (BITS_PER_LONG - 1)))` is:

- if `nbits` is a multiple of `BITS_PER_LONG`, an `unsigned long` with all bits set,
- otherwise, an `unsigned long` with the low `nbits%BITS_PER_LONG` bits set.

Comment: This answer is correct and can be verified with the trivial C program: `#include <stdio.h>

#define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#define BITMAP_LAST_WORD_INDEX(nbits) (~0UL >> (-(nbits) & (BITS_PER_LONG - 1)))

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 for (int nbits = 0; nbits < BITS_PER_LONG; ++nbits) {
  printf("%d -> %04lx\n", nbits, BITMAP_LAST_WORD_INDEX(nbits));
 }
 return 0;
}`

Comment: You are right. I missed that part.